# What is the best way to select rows belonging to other IDs which have the exact same rows as an ID in question using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a database where I keep track of people and their hobbies, and there are two tables: People and Hobbies. Now if there exists a person named Tom from table People with the two hobbies 'fishing' and 'jogging' in table Hobbies, how can I check for other persons who have **exactly** these two hobbies? I want to exclude people who have, for instance, the hobbies Fishing, Jogging AND Gaming. I have tried the following:

```
select name 
from people
where name IN( 
select name_hobbyist
from hobby
where hobby IN(
select hobby
from hobby 
where name_hobbyist =(
select name
from people
where name = 'Tom'
) 
)
)
order by name asc
```

And it returns no rows.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use: MySql, SQL Server, Oracle..... DBeaver is just the software you use to access the database.

Comment: Ahh my bad. it is postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the names of people in the table `hobby` you don't need the table `people`.

You can `group by name_hobbyist` and use the aggregate function `string_agg()` in the `having` clause to apply the condition:

```
select name_hobbyist 
from hobby
where name_hobbyist <> 'Tom'
group by name_hobbyist 
having string_agg(hobby, ',' order by hobby) = (
  select string_agg(hobby, ',' order by hobby)
  from hobby
  where name_hobbyist = 'Tom'
)
```